# FB.ui apprequest fails on friends who have not accepted friend request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

I have an app in which I'm allowing users to send app invite requests based on friend lists.

I am using the call:

```
            FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'My App Request',
                to: users,
            }, requestCallback);
```

The issue that I am having is that I make the request to GraphAPI /FRIENDLIST_ID/members? It is returning members who have no yet accepted a friend request and so when I make the apprequests call above I get the following error:

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Can only send requests to friends or users of this application.

Is there a way to make the FB.ui call with specific users and then if it fails replace the request with the to field blank so the user can select the users they want to send to?  Or is there a way to tell if someone has accepted your friend request or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's your implementation is not the intended usage. To be most user-friendly at all, you shouldn't pre-fill the "to"-section, so the user itself can choose which friends he wants to invite.

but, back to your implementation:

you can check in requestCallback, what response you're receiving. If it's an error, you should be able to call FB.ui again without the "to" field.

Comment: I would normally completely agree with you but we have a specific reason for doing this.  We are also giving them the option to select who they want to send to.  I will try your suggestion, thanks!